# Copy string from dictionary and remove it afterwards

Tags: string, dictionary, swift3, copy

i got a `textview` where i want to set a `String` from a `dictionary` and delete the `String` afterwards from the dictionary. How do i copy the String and not the pointer?

```
var title =  items["name"]
items.removeValue(forKey: "name")
return title
```

if i do it as in my code-snipped the `return value` is `nil`, because i just copied the pointer of items["name"). There is no copy method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mutable copy like this-

```
    var items = ["name":"1"]
    var title =  items["name"]
    title = title?.mutableCopy() as? String
    items.removeValue(forKey: "name")
    print(title!)
```